# Spring aop: advice never reached

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I've create this pointcut:

```
@Pointcut(value = "execution(* net.space.service.RepositoryService.createDocumentFromBytes(..))")
public void groupBytesMethod() {
}
```

and this advice:

```
@Around("groupBytesMethod()")
public Object groupMetrics(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    Object result = point.proceed();
}
```

I've set a breakpoint, but it's never reached.

```
package net.space.service;

@Service
public class RepositoryService {
    private Reference createDocumentFromBytes(String id, byte[] content) throws IOException {...}
    public Reference groupDocuments(@NotNull RepositoryGroupForm groupForm) {
        return this.createDocumentFromBytes("id", new byte[10]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make this work, I would suggest use an annotation,something like :

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GroupBytesMethod {
}
```

Then

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(GroupBytesMethod)") // use full package name of annotation
    public Object groupMetrics(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        // do something before
        Object result = null;
        try {
          result = point.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
          // handle an exception
        }
        // do something after
        return result;
    }
}
```

Example [here](https://github.com/gregclinker/aspect-example)

Comment: @Jordi my example works, it has a test in it to prove, you can download it and take it from there.

Comment: I think, I've realized what was wrong... `createDocumentFromBytes` throws an exception. I've edited post.

Comment: So is your problem solved or do you have a concrete question before accepting this answer? You did a minor edit in your sample code but said nothing about follow-up problems.

Comment: @Jordi I've tidied up the answer, for future reference, with your fix.